# Is there a way to replace all nulls in a table at once?

Tags: powerquery, m

If I have a table like this:

[image]

How might I replace all nulls with blanks at once?

I'd prefer a solution that dynamically accounts for column names, to account for more or less columns and differing column names. So `Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"})` would not be what I'm after.

I'm thinking the solution would rely on somehow using something like`{Table.ColumnNames(tablename here)}` in place of `{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4"}`but when I try that, I get an error:

[image]

I'm sure I just don't understand the proper syntax. I'll certainly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I just figured it out. I needed to drop the brackets.
I changed...

`Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")})`

to...

`Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Custom",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"))`

and it seemed to work.